# subsitute word from regex to another word

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code with me, it produce the img title of specified text,

let say the title = waterfallfountainpicture20x20, how do i replace the word fountain with lagoon so it would become waterfalllagoonpicture20x20?

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $result);
$img = array();
foreach( $result[0] as $img_tag)
{
    preg_match_all('/(title)="([^"]*)"/i',$img_tag, $img[$img_tag]);
}

//print_r($img);
foreach ($img as $imgg)
 echo $imgg[2][0];
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

well since you've already pulled out the image tags, and it sounds like you know exactly what you are replacing (static text), might be better for you to just use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) but if you want to go the regex route...

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $result);
$img = array();
$sub = "fountain";
$rep = "lagoon";
foreach( $result[0] as $img_tag)
{
    $img[] = preg_replace('/(title\s?=\s?["\'][^"\']*)'.$sub.'/i','${1}'.$rep,$img_tag);
}
```

Comment: this does replace the string however text become <img title="waterfalllagoonpicture20x20" />, instead of waterfalllagoonpicture20x20, how do i use str_replace? i am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question correctly. You could try using [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) instead of preg_match_all.